# Selecting specific files for athena

Tags: amazon-athena

While creating a table in Athena, I am not able to create tables using specific files. Is there any way to select all the files starting with "year_2019" from a given bucket? For e.g.
s3://bucketname/prefix/year_2019*.csv

---

The documentation is very clear about it and it is not allowed.

From:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html

> Athena reads all files in an Amazon S3 location you specify in the
>   CREATE TABLE statement, and cannot ignore any files included in the
>   prefix. When you create tables, include in the Amazon S3 path only the
>   files you want Athena to read. Use AWS Lambda functions to scan files
>   in the source location, remove any empty files, and move unneeded
>   files to another location.

I will like to know if the community has found some work-around :)

Comment: You can try create a table using all the files and then using condition on the hidden synthetic `"$path"` column to filter what you want. Did you try that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately the filesystem abstraction that Athena uses for S3 doesn't support this. It requires table locations to look like directories, and Athena will add a slash to the end of the location when listing files.

There is a way to create tables that contain only a selection of files, but as far as I know it does not support wildcards, only explicit lists of files.

What you do is you create a table with

```
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat'
```

and then instead of pointing the `LOCATION` of the table to the actual files, you point it to a prefix with a single `symlink.txt` file (or point each partition to a prefix with a single `symlink.txt`). In the `symlink.txt` file you add the S3 URIs of the files to include in the table, one per line.

The only documentation that I know of for this feature is the [S3 Inventory documentation for integrating with Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html).

You can also find a full example in this Stackoverflow response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55069330/1109

Comment: Is there any chance that symbolic link file support will be discontinued by Athena in the future?

Comment: Very unlikely, it's a Hive feature, and that's not going to go away. It's been around since a very long time.

Comment: How many times did you encounter timeout error (due to 30 minutes limit)? Will that be a big issue if my data grows beyond a few hundred GB?

Comment: I've only encountered timeouts on multi-terabyte queries, or queries with way too many joins. You should be fine unless you do self joins on those hundreds of GB.