# Query by "$path" field

Tags: amazon-athena

I want to query by a file / group of files under a partition inside a table.
I found out that when I'm using the "$path" field Athena scans the entire partition, and not the files I want

Is there a way to make this kind of query more efficient and scan only the given files? Something like partition pruning for files...

Here is a sample query:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE day = '2019-01-01'
      AND "$path" = 's3://my-bucket/my-table/day=2019-01-01/my_file'
```

Comment: I don't know about Athena (Theo knows best), but this "just works" when using Presto without Athena's modifications.

Answer (score 2):

*Update in 2023: Athena now supports skipping files based on predicates on $path*

<strike>No. It's not possible to get Athena to scan only the file you want by using `$path`, or any other method that I know of, without partitioning your table differently.</strike>

If this is a common operation I suggest making your partitions smaller and match the files better, but if it's just something you do once in a while I wouldn't worry too much about it.

If you have multiple access patterns, and this isn't the primary, but still not uncommon pattern, you can create a separate table using the `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat` input format, and create a 1:1 structure of partitions with `symlink.txt` files pointing to the files of the original table. You can read more about this way of creating tables in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066760/partition-athena-query-by-s3-created-date/55069330#55069330) (the second half) – but I think it will be a very complicated way to solve it.