# how to create multiple table from multiple folder with one location path and athena should also work on it with glue crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have tried this not achieving required results-
I have multiple CSV files in a folder of s3 bucket but when it creates multiple table for it then Athena returns zero results so I made a different folder for each file then it works fine.
problem-
but if in future more folders will be added then I have to go to crawler and have to add a new location path for each newly added folder so is there any way to do it automatically or some other way to do it. I am using glue crawler and s3 bucket athena for query run on multiple CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general a table needs all of its files to be in a directory, and no other files to be in that directory.

There is however, a mechanism that makes it possible to create tables that include just specific files. You can read more about that in the the second part of this answer: [Partition Athena query by S3 created date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066760/partition-athena-query-by-s3-created-date/55069330#55069330) (scroll down a bit after the horizontal rule). You can also find an example in the S3 Inventory documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html